# Netty 4 вызов метода writeAndFlush несколько раз

Tags: netty

Я пытаюсь два раза вызвать метод writeAndFlush   в методе channelRead на стороне сервера, но клиент почему - то получает только одно сообщение вместо двух.

на стороне сервера:

```
public class SimpleProcessingHandler extends   ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws InterruptedException {

    ByteBuf b = ctx.alloc().buffer(1);
     b.writeByte(1);
    ctx.writeAndFlush(b).sync();
    ctx.writeAndFlush(b).sync();
}
}
```

на стороне клиента:

```
public class TimeClientHandler   extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {



    System.out.println(msg);
}
}
```

Comment: Цикл событий нельзя останавливать!

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, Всмысле?

Comment: Объясните как  правильно  посылать ответ  несколько раз в одном и том же методе channelRead  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В хэндлерах и колбэках нельзя выполнять блокирующих операций, к которым относится вызов `sync`. Это в лучшем случае приведёт к серьёзной деградации производительности, а в худшем к deadlock'у.
2. Транспортный уровень снизит у `ByteBuf` счётчик ссылок, что приведёт к освобождению памяти буфера и второй операции записи нечего будет записывать. Поэтому счётчик надо повысить - `b.retain()`.
3. Количество системных вызовов надо сводить к минимуму, так как они медленные и тормозят цикл событий. Поэтому либо

   ```
   ctx.write(b.retain());
   ctx.write(b);
   ctx.flush();
   ```

   либо ещё лучше

   ```
   public class SimpleProcessingHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
       @Override
       public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

           ByteBuf b = ctx.alloc().buffer(1);
           b.writeByte(1);
           ctx.write(b.retain());
           ctx.write(b);
       }

       @Override
       public void channelReadCompelete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
           ctx.flush();
       }
   }
   ```